# How to change specific highlight of a font color in vs code

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a `style.sass` file (as an example). I want to change a font color which denotes class name. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Open command palette, type `scope` and chose `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` command. Now you can click on a segment of text you are interesting in (in our case on `.someclassname`) which has `entity.other.attribute-name.class { "foreground": "#6495ed" }` scope and settings. Now open your `settings.json` (usually at `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`) and edit `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` property (if there isn't such a property add it).

Instead of "[Material Theme Lighter]" type your theme.

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Material Theme Lighter]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.class ",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#6495ed"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```